# Time Complexity from LeetCode

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

This is the code from LeetCode94. Binary Tree Inorder Traversal

```
class Solution {
public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if(root == null){
        return arr;
    }
    TreeNode curr = root;
    
    while(curr != null || !stack.isEmpty()){
        while(curr != null){
            stack.push(curr);
            curr = curr.left;
        }
        curr = stack.pop();
        arr.add(curr.val);
        curr = curr.right;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

How is the time complexity O(n)? Is that just because it iterates all nodes once?
I thought it would be O(n^2) since I have double while loop.

Comment: The number of times each loop is iterated is typically way less than `n`, in this scenario.  The total number of iterations of the inner loop is `n`, regardless of how many loops there are, and that's what controls the big-O.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that each node of the tree is being ‘visited’ 3 times:

1. When this node is added to the stack
2. When you popped all the nodes from the stack that are from the left branch of that node
3. Similarly for the right branch of that node

This means we are in a case of 3n which is O(n)